# Deferring function call until Json Schema references have been resolved (async pattern)

Tags: javascript, jsonschema

I have multiple json schemas. If not familiar, it allows you to specify exactly what a json payload will look like. More info [here](http://json-schema.org/), best examples [here](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/).

Imagine I have to consume a schema and resolve all references, some of these references might require HTTP calls to the server where my web app is based and where other json schemas reside. Some of these might even have some '$ref' key that need to be resolved.

Example schema:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "address": {
            "type": "object"
            , "properties": {
                "street_address": { "type": "string" },
                "city":           { "type": "string" },
                "state":          { "type": "string" }
            }
            , "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
         }
     }
     , "allOf": [
         { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
         , { "properties": {
             "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] }
             , "metadata" : { 
                 "$ref" : "http://localhost:5000/api/someJsonSchema.json"
               }
             }
           }
     ]
     , "additionalProperties": false
}
```

In the example above, a certain json object will be an address which needs to make an HTTP request to the localhost url to get the json schema that defines what the value of the 'metadata' key looks like. This schema sometimes will have multiple $refs inside of itself which need to be retrieved before moving forward.

Each time I find a $ref in a schema, I might have to make an HTTP call to get the required information. With potentially MULTIPLE http calls being needs to resolve an entire schema, how do I verify that this json object contains no more $ref objects inside each schema that I get?

These schemas I grab can potentially have other $ref objects that need to be examined before moving forward.

What is the best way to go about this? Right now, I have each json schema as a standard javascript object saved in memory. On each successful GET request where I receive a $ref, I fill in the reference in the original schema and manually run through the entire tree verifying that the $refs have been taken out.

I am trying to only use ES5 here.

My code to resolve all references looks like this:

```
Schema.prototype.resolveReferences = function(callback) {
    while (this.referenceObjects.length > 0) {
        var url = this.referenceObjects.pop();
        this.resolveReference(url, callback);
    }
};

Schema.prototype.resolveReference = function(url, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var uriParts = this.getUriParts(url);
    if (this.schemaEnvironment.schemaMap.hasOwnProperty(uriParts.url.concat('#'))) {
    var data = this.schemaEnvironment.schemaMap[uriParts.url.concat('#')];
    var jsonPointerData = this.schemaEnvironment.getJsonPointerData(data.expanded.schema.json, uriParts.jsonPointer, data.base);
    this.insertReferenceObject(jsonPointerData, url, self.expanded);
} else {
    var urlWithNamespace = "/api/schemas?namespace=".concat(encodeURI(uriParts.url));
    client.get(urlWithNamespace, function(data) {
        self.schemaEnvironment.addSchema(data);
        var expandedRefSchema = self.schemaEnvironment.schemaMap[data.base].expanded;
        var jsonPointerData = self.schemaEnvironment.getJsonPointerData(expandedRefSchema.schema.json, uriParts.jsonPointer, data.base);
        //var jsonPointerData = self.schemaEnvironment.getJsonPointerData(data.schema.json, uriParts.jsonPointer);
        self.insertReferenceObject(jsonPointerData, url, self.expanded);
        self.hasRefs = false;
        self.hasReferences(self.expanded);
        if (!self.hasRefs) {
            //if there are no more references, invoke callback function
            callback(self.base);
        }
    });
}
}

Schema.prototype.hasReferences = function(tree) {
for (var i in tree) {
    if (i === '$ref') {
        this.hasRefs = true;
    }
    if (tree[i] !== null && typeof(tree[i]) == 'object') {
        this.hasReferences(tree[i]);
    }
}
}
```

There has to be a better way than traversing the json tree everytime.

Comment: Use promises and treat them as return values of the resolver function. You should not need to traverse more than once.

Comment: @Bergi I have been using Ajax requests with success and error callbacks. Anyway of explaining while sticking to ES5?

Comment: What does this have to do with ES5?

Comment: I haven't been using promises at all. I thought promises were created starting in ES6

Comment: Promises are an abstraction that have been implemented in many languages and libraries, including a native implementation shipped with ES6 JS engines. But that doesn't stop you from learning about them and using them in ES5.

Comment: ajv.compileAsync resolves $ref's while processing the schema: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#api-compileAsync